# Where does a BasicReject with requeue actually go?

Tags: rabbitmq

This seems like a simple question, but I'm having a hard time finding a definitive answer. If in RabbitMQ 3.6.1 I have a queue that looks like this:

```
5  4  3  2  1  <= head
```

And I consume message 1, then do:

```
channel.BasicReject(ea.DeliveryTag, true);
```

Will the `1` end up on the end of the queue or at the head of the queue (assuming for the sake of simplicity that nobody else is consuming the queue at the time)? So will I end up with:

```
1  5  4  3  2  <= head
```

or:

```
5  4  3  2  1  <= head
```

And is there anyway to control it (one way would be to ack the message and repost it entirely I suppose)? I actually want the first situation because I'm rejecting `1` because a particular resource needed to process that message is currently unavailable. So I'd like to throw it back on the queue to be processed later (when the resource is available) or get picked up by somebody else (who has resources available). But I don't want to throw it back just to keep picking it up again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say the answer is [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html), I'll quote a part:

> Messages can be returned to the queue using AMQP methods that feature
>   a requeue parameter (basic.recover, basic.reject and basic.nack), or
>   due to a channel closing while holding unacknowledged messages. Any of
>   these scenarios caused messages to be requeued at the back of the
>   queue for RabbitMQ releases earlier than 2.7.0. From RabbitMQ release
>   2.7.0, messages are always **held in the queue in publication order, even in the presence of requeueing or channel closure**.

So we could assume that RMQ is implemented in that way the messages are not deleted form the queue (physically deleted) until they are ACKed, they may have a ACKed flag or whatever.

Comment: Thanks.  Learned something new about the newer way.

Comment: So it goes to the end then?

Comment: ```When a message is requeued, it will be placed to its original position in its queue, if possible. If not (due to concurrent deliveries and acknowledgements from other consumers when multiple consumers share a queue), the message will be requeued to a position closer to queue head.``` - From Rabbitmq's official site - https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html

Comment: Can you actually *answer* the question? Where does it go? To the head of to the tail of the queue?

Comment: I don't know why the downvote.. Also @Maggyero don't know what is not clear. Look at the bold part of my answer, especially the words "publication order" That means exactly the same thing as in smc's comment after the fist comma, the part "original position". So there, I've quoted what was quoted. As you noticed, there was no mentioned of neither "head" nor "tail". Disclamer for moderators: I wasn't being sarcastic or anything, the comment required further explanation and this is the best one I can give.

Comment: As you noticed it was not clear not only for me but also for @simPod whom you ignored. The question was "Will the 1 end up on the end of the queue or at the head of the queue (assuming for the sake of simplicity that nobody else is consuming the queue at the time)?" And the answer is: the *head* of the queue.

Answer (score 7):

Explicitly answering for anyone who, like me, came to this question late and needed a non-"read the docs" answer:

> When a message is requeued, it will be placed to its original position in its queue, if possible. If not (due to concurrent deliveries and acknowledgements from other consumers when multiple consumers share a queue), the message will be requeued to a position closer to queue head. - From Rabbitmq's official site - rabbitmq.com/nack.html – smc

To expand on this comment from the (currently) top answer using your example

> I have a queue that looks like this:

`5  4  3  2  1  <= head`

> And I consume message 1

Queue is now: `5  4  3  2  <= head`

> then do: `channel.BasicReject(ea.DeliveryTag, true);`

Your result will be the same as initial,

`5  4  3  2  1  <= head`

If you have only one consumer. With multiple consumers it may be possible for the following:

Initial: `5  4  3  2  1  <= head`

Consumer 1 accepts message: `5  4  3  2  <= head`

Consumer 2 accepts message while consumer 1 is processing: `5  4  3  <= head`

Consumer 1 decides to reject and requeue, resulting in: `5  4  3  1  <= head`