# Do there any ways to know what message is unacked?

Tags: rabbitmq

Recently, I have encounted some Confusing questions ，my rabbitmq always blocked beacause many messages doesn't get “ack” ，but I don't know what exactly messages cause it blocking. So I want to ask is there any way to find what mesaages make the block ?

Comment: rabbitmq client blocked or rabbitmq server blocked?

Comment: The interesting question is: Why does the consumer not ACK the message?

Answer (score 0):

If a message is not acknowledged (rejected) with requeue it goes back to its original position in the queue (or closer to the head of the queue).

This means that your next dequeue would return the same message which *may* be problematic.  If this is your case you could requeue the message and ack the original in order to "move" the problematic message to the back of the queue.

You may also have an additional problem of thrashing your queue when you have only "problematic" messages remaining.

Perhaps this may shed some light: [Where does a BasicReject with requeue actually go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709896/where-does-a-basicreject-with-requeue-actually-go)